# How would you make a set B a subset of A

Tags: set, scheme, lisp

I have seen plenty of examples stating how to find the subsets of a given set but how would you make a set sub to another? So Set B is a subset of set A, how would this be implemented? I'm currently working with scheme for the recursive nature but the book only showed how to list subsets not how to make a subset.
Edit: Book i am using is "the little schemer"

Comment: Remove an element from a set. There, that's a subset of it.

Comment: But if you would remove the element wouldn't that destroy the relationship?

Comment: What do you mean by "the book only showed how to list subsets"? Which book are you working from, and did it show how to make a list of all subsets of a given set?

Comment: And i am asking if i already know the subset how can i establish the relationship between the subset and its "parent"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you know both *A* and *B*, then there is nothing to *make*.  Either one is a subset of the other or not.

You can find out whether this is the case with e. g. [`subset?`](https://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/sets.html#%28def._%28%28lib._racket%2Fset..rkt%29._subset~3f%29%29) in Racket, [`lset<=`](https://www.gnu.org/software/guile/manual/html_node/SRFI_002d1-Set-Operations.html) in Guile Scheme, [`subsetp`](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/f_subset.htm#subsetp) in Common Lisp.  If you can't find a ready made function in your language and implementation, you can also test whether exactly one of the set-differences (*A* without *B* and *B* without *A*) is empty.

Comment: Thank you so much. I was overthinking the whole concept.